# Vendored framework with dependencies cocoapods linking error

Tags: swift, xcode, frameworks, cocoapods

I need to ship a compiled framework - let's call it Abc.framework with cocoapods.

This framework has some dependencies - let's assume I need [Nomosi](https://github.com/marioIannotta/nomosi) and [KeychainSwift](https://github.com/evgenyneu/keychain-swift).

Podfile:

```rb
platform :ios, '10.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'Abc' do
  pod "Nomosi", "0.1.2"
  pod "KeychainSwift", "18.0"
end
```

I'm able to build a fat framework using a script [like this](https://gist.github.com/MarioIannotta/0603fe1830bb426bdc6b936f73c6241e).

Podspec:

```rb
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name             = 'Abc'
  s.version          = '0.0.1'
  s.summary          = 'Abc description.'
  s.description      = 'Abc looong description.'
  s.homepage         = 'https://test.com'
  s.license          = { :type => 'MIT', :file => 'LICENSE' }
  s.author           = { 'Author' => 'me@test-email.com' }
  s.source           = { :git => 'https://github.com/test/this-is-not-a-repo.git', :tag => s.version.to_s }
  s.ios.deployment_target = '10.0'
  s.public_header_files = "Build/Abc.framework/Headers/*.h"
  s.source_files = "Build/Abc.framework/Headers/*.h"
  s.vendored_frameworks = 'Build/Abc.framework'
  s.dependency 'KeychainSwift', '18.0'
  s.dependency 'Nomosi', '0.1.2'
end
```

Now if I create a demo project using the local pod it compiles but there's a runtime crash:

```
dyld: Symbol not found: _$s6Nomosi15ServiceResponseP5parse4dataxSg10Foundation4DataV_tKFZTq
  Referenced from: /Users/mario/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/DFF39FE4-F274-4E4E-9710-AB24B043CFB0/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/A9C811DE-19D6-4535-996B-B5F2D142D691/AbcDemo.app/Frameworks/Abc.framework/Abc
```

If the podspec points to the actual source code (instead of shipping the compiled fat framework) the app doesn't crash.

This is probably related to some linking error in the framework (@rpath?) but I really don't know how to fix it.

Comment: I had very similar problem. This helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64657668/custom-framework-dyld-symbol-not-found-s11cryptoswift7paddingo5pkcs7ya2cmf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The build script might need the option `BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION=YES`

I can only find minimal docs at https://xcodebuildsettings.com/:

> Ensures that your libraries are built for distribution. For Swift,
> this enables support for library evolution and generation of a module
> interface file.

I'm assuming that the option should also make sure that all symbols that could be used by any random client library or app are properly exported.

Comment: Paul, can you explain why this is needed?

Comment: @Honey Added more to the answer